# How to define a queue for QueueBrowser?

Tags: java, queue, jms, ibm-mq

I was reading example1 in the following webpage:

http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=javax.jms.QueueBrowser

In the line:

```
QueueBrowser browser = session.createBrowser(queue1);
```

where is

```
queue1
```

defined?

This is my example of me opening and closing a connection:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Connection.class);
    String hostname = "xxxxxx";
    int port = 1442;
    String queueManager = "xxxxxxxx";
    String channel = "xxxxxxxxxx";
    String queueName = "xxxxxxxxxx";
    String keystore = "xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/ssclient_test.ks";
    String truststore = "cxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/client_test.ts";
    String suiteName = "xxx_xxx_xxxx_xxx_xxx_xxx";
    String keyStorePassKey = "xxx_KEYSTORE";
    SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = createSslSocketFactory(new File(keystore), new File(truststore), 
            keyStorePassKey);
    MQXAQueueConnectionFactory mqConnFactory = new MQXAQueueConnectionFactory();
    mqConnFactory.setHostName(hostname);
    mqConnFactory.setPort(port);
    mqConnFactory.setTransportType(JMSC.MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP);
    mqConnFactory.setQueueManager(queueManager);
    mqConnFactory.setChannel(channel);
    mqConnFactory.setUseConnectionPooling(true);
    mqConnFactory.setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
    mqConnFactory.setSSLCipherSuite(suiteName);
    QueueConnection queueConnection = mqConnFactory.createQueueConnection();
    QueueSession queueSession = queueConnection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    queueSession.close();
    queueConnection.close();
}
```

How would I define a queue in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The createBrowser method expects a queue to be put in. 
For that you'll need to create a new suitable queue instance.

E.g.

```
ActiveMQQueue myQueue = new ActiveMQQueue("My queue");
QueueBrowser browser = session.createBrowser(myQueue);
```

Take a look at this guide if interested:
https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jms/jms-queuebrowser-example/

Comment: i used line 28 from example 5, which provided the solution.

Comment: @user3809938 glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

In your example code the `MQXAQueueConnectionFactory` is instantiated empty and then all of the attributes filled in using setter methods.  You could take the same approach by instantiating a new and empty destination of type `Queue` and then using [setter methods](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJMSClasses/com/ibm/mq/jms/MQQueue.html?lang=en) to provide sufficient detail for MQ to resolve it to an actual queue.

Alternatively, you could take the approach from Example 3 on the same linked page and look up the queue by establishing a JNDI context and retrieving a pre-existing managed object by name.  The managed object can have any or all of the properties documented in [*Properties of IBM MQ classes for JMS objects*](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q111800_.htm?lang=en).

In either of these cases the queue being opened must already exist on the queue manager.  For example, you could specify `SYSTEM.DEFAULT.LOCAL.QUEUE` as the queue to be browsed since you can be pretty sure it exists on the queue manager.

Answer (score 1):

You can call QueueSession.createQueue(qname).  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/QueueSession.html#createQueue(java.lang.String)